# Prevent application execution during ClickOnce install

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have an application that I need to deploy via ClickOnce on a web page, but I need it to only install the application and not execute it automatically after the install is complete. The user should have to manually start the application from the start menu - even after the initial install.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install ClickOnce without running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513768/install-clickonce-without-running)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the MSDN article *[How to: Disable URL Activation of ClickOnce Applications by Using the Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404230.aspx)*.