# Why does the ClickOnce Deployment installer run the application during installation?

Tags: installation, clickonce

**Why** does the ClickOnce Deployment installer run the application during installation?

Details:

For an XNA 4.0 application I am prototyping it runs once. If you have Avast! installed and with its Deep Screen feature enabled, it will run twice (Avast! kills it and re-runs it).

Note:

This is similar to, but not the same as, [Install ClickOnce without running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513768/install-clickonce-without-running). Please see that question for a solution to make it stop running the application. [The answer is right here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404268.aspx), you must use MageUI.exe. Here, I am only interested in understanding **why** it runs the application. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You mention that Avast might be the cause. You have tried running the app with Avast turned off, correct?  And what are the results?

Comment: @SoylentGreen, I have turned off Avast's Deep Screen (a real-time virus scan for new .exe files being executed), and the results are that the application only runs once, but still runs. So, I am in the same place as before. Why does it do this? The "why" is what I am interested in. MageUI solves it apparently. I'll add these notes to my question.