# How do I keep my C# program from running as it's installed?

Tags: c#, installation, scheduled-tasks

I'm developing a console application in C# that should only run once on a specific day/time each week. When I modify, publish and install the application, the installer always runs the program. I had to add an if statement at the beginning of my code to compare the current date/time that I have to manually change any time I recompile/republish just to make sure the program doesn't run when I install the new version. While that works, it seems silly to have to do that.

I'm sure I'm missing an obvious setting somewhere, and I'm just waiting for some hero to give me my Head-Slap-Moment-of-the-Day.

Thanks!!

(Edited to more accurately describe the schedule.)

Comment: Who will run it on that very specific time each day? What is the logic that decides whether now is a right time?

Comment: I think you are looking for `Windows Service` Application. Read more here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So you are saying your installer is running the program automatically? Like a "run when finished" option? Might help to know how you are creating your installer, is there any think like a "run when finished"  setting you can change?

Comment: I use the Publish Wizard to publish the installer to a network location, then run setup.exe to install. I use Scheduled Tasks to schedule the app to run at the appropriate day/time.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is the inability to control whether Install or publish process will run the program - you can have your main expect a certain command line parameter to run, without it - it will simply exit.

If the program is run via a scheduler, have the scheduler pass in the correct argument.

For example

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   if (args.Length == 1 && args[0].Equals("NOW_IS_THE_TIME"))
   {
       // Run
   }
}
```

You could also, save a flag in your settings indicating if it's the first run or not, like proposed in [Install ClickOnce without running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513768/install-clickonce-without-running)

Comment: While this solution is better than what I'm currently doing, it still seems kludgy. I just want the installer to install the app and not run it.

Comment: @MarkPetereit - I agree, but then your question should revolve around the specific Install\Publish process you're using. Like I said - this is for the case where you don't control the Install\Publish

Comment: I understand. Your solution doesn't answer my question.