# There is no "Run after install" checkbox in Mono Game ClickOnce installer

Tags: c#, mono, xna, xna-4.0

I have created a game with Mono Game 3.4 distributed by the ClickOnce wizard, using Visual Studio Express 2015.

I would like to distribute only on Windows. The ClickOnce wizard works well, but I don't want the program to automatically run after ClickOnce. But how do I do it?

Comment: try using MageUi tools: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404268.aspx

Comment: so that functioin is "disable URL activation for your application" ?

Comment: to disable auto-run after install. and here are more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513768/install-clickonce-without-running